# check boxes are not functioning in react-bootstrap-table-next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am using `react-bootstrap-table2`, to make tables, I have encounter an issue i.e

I want o have a checkbox inside my table, so I am following [This, mention in the documentation](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Row%20Selection&selectedStory=Selection%20Class&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel), but I am getting unexpected result.

**My code**

**For selecting the row**

```
const selectRow = {
    mode: 'checkbox',
    clickToSelect: true,
    classes: 'selection-row',
};
```

**Table rendering**

```
  <BootstrapTable
    keyField="id"
    data={tableData[0].rowsData}
    columns={tableData[0].columnsData}
    selectRow={selectRow}
 />
```

I Think issue is coming because of my data, as it is nested one And I am rendering it, but I am not able to resolve it.

**My data**

```
let tableData = [
{
  rowsData: [
    {
      fname: "john",
      lname: "smith"
    },
    {
      fname: "steve",
      lname: "warn"
    },
    {
      fname: "michel",
      lname: "clark"
    }
  ],
  columnsData: [
    {
      dataField: "fname",
      text: "First name",
      sort: true
    },
    {
      dataField: "lname",
      text: "last Name",
      sort: true
    }
  ]
}
```

];

**Here is my code sandbox link [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-dream-sqywq?file=/src/App.js:914-1072)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling `keyField="id"` yet each of your `rowsData` has no `id`. Give each of them an `id` and it should work.

[image: Edit holy-feather-s0upd]

Comment: ohh yup, a small mistake :(, I have one thing to clarify, could u help me out

Comment: Yes sure, what is it?

Comment: Now I want to do click event on any of column's cell, how can I do that, here in mu case suppose I want to add onclick on lastname, or how can I handel this check uncheck event, here when I check I want that particular row, or on multi check after click on button get all selected data, Just want to know the approach

Comment: Ohhh this my first time checking out `react-bootstrap-table2`, but it seems what you want is documented [here](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/table-props.html#rowevents-object). I also updated the codesandbox

Comment: ya got it, small thing is, here when I click on any row the checkbox is checking, how to do that checked or unchecked on checkbox click only, can I do that as I have not found any example in documentation there

Comment: Its all in the [docs](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/row-select-props.html#selectrowclicktoselect-bool), set `clickToSelect: false`.